# Adding element to beginning of the vector in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector, append

I have this for loop that calls functions that result in vectors of numbers

For example the vector would result in:

```
[1] 42 42 6 693 6222
```

from the for loop above.

I want to add "x" to the beginning of each of these vectors.
It seems inefficient to go

```
append("x", vec1)
# This is an example of what I want produced:
[1] x 42 42 6 693 6222
```

multiple times. Is there a way of including the addition of the "x" as the first element inside the for loop?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you providee a reproducible example is it vector or list

Comment: I added examples to the question, hope its clearer now

Answer (score 8):

just use c(), for e.g. 
`a <- c(1,2,3)`

> a: 1 2 3

```
b <- c("x",a)
```

> b: "x" "1" "2" "3"

Comment: yes but i have so many vectors, that it would be time consuming to add that to every vector

Comment: The only way to add a new element on a already existing array is use c() and create a new one or like you did using the append function.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to add new element at the beginning of a `list`

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) c('x', x))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c(42, 42, 6 ,693 ,6222), c(42, 42, 6 ,693 ,6222))
```